# Google Custom Search - filter data from within a page

Tags: filtering, google-custom-search

I am using Google Custom Search to enable users to search within my website. I have one page that displays a list of references (to scientific publications) as well as other content (dynamic). I would like to display the results so that references including the search term are filtered into their own tab - but I can only see how to label a whole page, not just a section of a page. This means I can filter for 'references', but get other content in my results, not just the references. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible I suppose. And I had done it sometime back and it had worked as expected. Have a look at these links -
[Tech Republic Set up Google Custom Search](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/set-up-a-google-custom-search-engine-for-your-website/) and
[Google Custom Search](http://googlecustomsearch.blogspot.in/2009/10/structured-custom-search.html)